# How to work out the stamp duty rate for each band using excel?

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to work out how to calculate stamp duty at each rate band using excel and struggling to do so, whatever I try is to no avail.

I have managed to calculate stamp duty of the overall price using the SUMPRODUCT formula but what I am really looking to do is calculate it at each band. For instance. If a house costs £300,000, what I want to know is how much it costs at each rate as described here https://www.gov.uk/stamp-duty-land-tax/residential-property-rates

Sorry if I did not explain myself clearly, I could not copy the different rates here as it got messed up.

I hope someone can help, I have been working on this for quite some time now, I understand there are calculators available online but I want to be able to do it in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. In columns C and D, fill down the formulas to row 8, and given the property value in C1, the result will be given in D10.

```
    A       B           C                       D       
1           Value       1825000
2
3 Band      Cutoff      Value exceeding cutoff  Duty paid in band
4 0%        125000      =MIN(C$1, B4)           =MAX(A4*C4, 0)
5 2%        250000      =MIN(C$1-B4, B5-B4)
6 5%        925000
7 10%       1500000
8 12%       9999999999
9
10                      Total duty paid         =SUM(D5:D8)
```